# XML documentation not found when publishing a .Net Framework web API?

Tags: c#, .net, api

I scratched my head over this one for a few hours. I followed Microsoft's tutorial on [adding API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages#adding-api-documentation). That all worked as expected on my local machine, but when published to my production IIS server, I got an error saying the XmlDocument.xml could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although enabling the "XML documentation file" checkbox in the project properties > build > output section does create the file, it does not add it to the project for some reason. That's why the App_Data folder in my solution explorer was empty.

The solution is simple. Right-click on the App_Data folder and select the add existing item option. Select the generated XML documentation file in the "App_Data" folder of your project's build location. Publish again.

I hope someone can find this useful.